# How to provide Laravel session persistence, when pushing data?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form and it send requests to the Laravel. Laravel controller catch requests and store data in session by push method, for example

```
$basename = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_BASENAME);

if (!$request->session()->exists('upload')) {

    $request->session()->put('upload', []);
}

$request->session()->push('upload', $basename);

var_dump($request->session()->get('upload'));
```

When form send two (or more) requests to Laravel, I expects to see in var_dump two (or more) values in array, but I see only one value. Why it can happening?

Thanks in advance!

PS. Simple example is showing that sequential push is works fine, and it create an array with two values.

```
$request->session()->put('upload', []); 
$request->session()->push('upload', $basename); 
$request->session()->push('upload', $basename); 

var_dump($request->session()->get('upload'));
```

I think that the reason is that requests are async, and Laravel retrieve session values in the request begin (when session is empty). Each request push new value in empty array and store it.

Comment: since you are overriding the key, How would you expect to have it multiple times?

Comment: @BasheerAhmedKharoti Ok, as I understand push method is the same as php native array_push. When we execute array_push in series, we get an array with two values. Or I'am mistake ?

Comment: @BasheerAhmedKharoti I see your answear but I don't agree with you. Please see my PS in a question.

Comment: I'm aware of `session()->has('key name')` I'm not aware of `session()->exists('key name')` . Are you sure it works?

Comment: @apokryfos From official docs: To determine if a value is present in the session, even if its value is null, you may use the exists method.

Comment: It seems to have been added since 5.3+. Good to know. Also, the way the session works is: Read session from the session storage, make updates to it, then save it back, so if you have multiple asynchronous requests it will not work well. The session will be read as empty by both and the one that will end up persisting will be the one that was written to last. You need to synchronise somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the [keep](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#storing-data) method

> If you need to keep your flash data around for several requests, you may use the reflash method, which will keep all of the flash data for an additional request. If you only need to keep specific flash data, you may use the keep method

```
session()->keep(['uploads']);
```

Comment: Some tests showing - when I'am using file as a session driver, keep method is not working. But when I change driver to memcached, keep method not even required. All works fine without it!